# Product Interest emails based on categories

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to design an email digest system, that will send a list of products that might be of interest to any user. This is what I have so far:

- Cronjob runs cron.php - Grabs all users, then loops through them to
  find matches.
- If any matches are found, an email is created and set
  in an email_queue table.
- A separate cron will check the queue table,
  and send emails if needed.

My question is if there is a better way to setup product interests, maybe at a different time or something.   I'm just thinking that if there are thousands of users, and thousands of products this could be a terribly inefficient way to design it.

Thanks

Comment: use sql to find your matches not by selecting everything then doing it in php

Comment: It's already using some crazy sql just to grab user's offers. But, it needs to be done for each user.  Just not sure how to go about that.